# L'Hospital's rule exception

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to-2}\frac{x^3-3x^2-10x}{(x+2)^2}$$ in this problem I tried using L'Hospital's rule but the outcome is not true why? Are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: L'Hopital works here. But indeed, it doesn't always work. It works only for indetermination of the form $0/0$ and $\infty /\infty $.

Comment: As @Surb says, L'hopital does work here, and you have likely made the mistake of continous application, despite the conditions of L'Hopital's rule not being met.

Comment: Its also in form of $0/0$ but result is not true

Comment: @MarvaJami would you mind editing your question to show your work?

Comment: Can you show how to use L'Hopital's rule is this particular problem?

Comment: $$\frac{3x^2-6x-10}{2(x+2)}$$ then i took the derivative of both numerator and denomentaor again giving $$\frac{6x-6}{2}$$ so answer is -9 am i doing it right??

Comment: Is $$\frac{3x^2-6x-10}{2(x+2)}$$ in the form of $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$?

Comment: So this condition should be satisfied in each step?

Comment: Yes, each time you apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule says that $\lim _{x \to a} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)}=\lim _{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)} {g'(x)}$ if the original limit is in the form $\frac 0 0$ and $\lim _{x \to a} \frac {f'(x)} {g'(x)}$ exists. This last condition is important. In this case this condition  is not satisfied and you cannot apply the rule.

Comment: If the limit is either $\pm \infty$ then the rule still works, right?

Comment: The rule assumes that the ratio of the derivatives has  finite limit. In the present case this ratio oscillates between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.  @ms_

Comment: @ms_: The rule works even if ratio of derivatives has an infinite limit. The problem here is that the ratio of derivatives tends to $\infty$ as $x\to - 2^{+}$ and to $-\infty $ as $x\to - 2^{-}$. By L'Hospital's Rule the same happens with original ratio.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You are right. Infinite limits are also fine.

Answer (score 0):

The given function simplifies to

$$\frac{x (x-5)}{x+2} $$

The graph has two asymptotes, one is vertical at $x=-2.$

You did not have $\frac{0}{0}, \frac{\infty}{\infty} $ forms so why did you think of L'Hospital's rule? It is not an exception.

Answer (score -2):

We find that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{ x^3 - 3x^2 - 10x }{ (x+2)^2 } &= \lim_{x\to -2} \frac{ 3x^2 - 6x - 10  }{ 2(x+2)  } \\
&= \pm\infty,
\end{align}
$$
because 
$$ 
\frac{ 3x^2 - 6x - 10  }{ 2(x+2)  } = \frac{1}{2} \left( 3x - 12 + \frac{14}{x+2} \right),
$$
and 
$$ \lim_{x \to -2} 3x-12 = -18, $$
which is finite, but 
$$ \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{14}{x+2} = \pm\infty. $$

Comment: The limit does  not exist. Your last line is not a valid statement.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i've only stated that the expression gets arbitrarily large positive and arbitrarily large negative, respectively, as we approach $-2$ from the right and from the left.